# How to modify query or table to fix inefficient query?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, query-optimization, clustered-index

I have following in MySQL slow query log. A select locks the table (or row I'm not sure) and seeks almost the entire table. I'm using MySQL 4.1.20 MyISAM.

```
# Query_time: 120  Lock_time: 108  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 641468
SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE EMAIL='user@blahblha.com' AND PASSWORD='8b45114747sdfas8dbcd02206a4sad0' LIMIT 1;
```

How can I fix this in a table that is used in production?

My table has the following structure:

[image]
And following indexes set:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try to add index to email and password

Comment: Actually, only the email itself would be required and keep the index paging smaller.  Even if there are two instances of an email in a list (not recommended), it would find 2 entries quickly and be done.

Comment: @DRapp What happens when I create an index on a field in table that is live and used in production?

Comment: @dev.e.loper, Nothing really, except it may cause a little lag time on other queries while the index is being constructed.  It shouldn't impact anything else except optimize other queries that might also be able to take advantage of the new index.